# How to do the phpexcel Outside Border

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use the below code for All Borders

```
$BStyle = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
    )
  )
);
```

Here i use

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A8:L8')->applyFromArray($BStyle);
```

But How can i give the Outside Border Like the below given screen

[image]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

As described in the [PHPExcel docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#styling-cell-borders) you use `outline`, so:

```
$BStyle = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'outline' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
    )
  )
);
```

All the available options are shown in this illustration

[image: This [illus]

Comment: outline not works proper for merged cell.any reason for that?

Comment: @ mark outline not works proper for merged cell.any reason for that? I also add question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983946/outline-border-not-working-in-laravel-excel