# outline border not working in laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In laravel excel I used outline border for table but it not work proper for merged cell.Outline border missing where cell merged in table.

```
$cellStyle = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'outline' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK
    )
  )
);
```

[image]